# Извлечение полей JSON в переменные Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Есть такой JSON ответ:

```
{"response":
    [{"aid":432696864,
      "owner_id":11111111,
      "artist":"Ciara",
      "title":"Paint It Black ( Movie version by Johnny L. ) OST Последний охотник на ведьм.",
      "duration":190,
      "url":"https:\/\/psv4.vk.me\/c611329\/u78009459\/audios\/2214a1d193fc.mp3?extra=sn5CXmyOD9TxSI2adKZgrqFZB6hwCVJHMdRJhqlmALnZa1z45HUI989V295mE17bMgK8MUkOvy260V0x9gjDMpXkDcpxkwvaswo68yM5ggomVg",
      "genre":18}
```

нужно вытащить отдельно в переменные поля `artist`, `title`, `url`, как это правильно делать

Comment: если ответ получен в виде строки, то надо вызвать `var o = JSON.parse(строка);`, а получить artist так `alert(o.response[0].artist);`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

запустите код и кликните по надписи, получите значение url

```js
   $(function() {
     var data = {
       "response": [{
         "aid": 432696864,
         "owner_id": 11111111,
         "artist": "Ciara",
         "title": "Paint It Black ( Movie version by Johnny L. ) OST Последний охотник на ведьм.",
         "duration": 190,
         "url": "https://psv4.vk.me/c611329/u78009459/audios/2214a1d193fc.mp3?extra=sn5CXmyOD9TxSI2adKZgrqFZB6hwCVJHMdRJhqlmALnZa1z45HUI989V295mE17bMgK8MUkOvy260V0x9gjDMpXkDcpxkwvaswo68yM5ggomVg",
         "genre": 18
       }]
     }
     $.each(data.response, function(indx, el) {
       $("<li/>", {
         html: "artist : " + el.artist + "<br> title: " + el.title,
         click: function() {
           alert(el.url);
         }
       }).appendTo("ul")

     });


   })
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: decimal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: а если в ответе не одна такая строка, а N

Comment: @aleksey тогда какой формат вывода -- идите циклом по всему массиву data.response и выводите куда вам нужно

Comment: В общем у меня titlt + artist выводятся в список, а мне нужно чобы при выборе одного пункта из сиска его url писался в переменную, которую я потом смогу использовать

Comment: @aleksey не понимаю вашей проблемы, вам показали как доставать переменные, идите циклом и делайте что вам нужно с любыми переменными

Comment: @aleksey смотрите ответ снова